# Modifying Images resolution and size to fit card view properiries

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have an error message from my android app , which using card view and recycle view , i think the problem with the size and resolution for allocated images, this is the error message :

> D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
>       D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>       W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41775898)
>       E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:586)
>                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
>                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:832)
>                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2988)
>                             at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1558)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
>                             at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:374)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
>                             at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:100)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:73)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:81)
>                             at pioneers.safwat.animals.RecyclerAdapterbirdse.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapterbirdse.java:71)
>                             at pioneers.safwat.animals.RecyclerAdapterbirdse.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapterbirdse.java:11)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6310)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6343)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5289)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5552)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5394)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5390)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2149)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1533)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1496)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:593)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3537)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3266)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3798)
>                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15213)
>                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
>                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1167)
>                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:852)
>                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:871)
>                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15213)
>                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
>                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15213)
>                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
>                             at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
>                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15213)
>                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
>                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15213)
>                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
>                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
>                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
>                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
>                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15213)
>                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
>                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
>                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15213)
>                             at android.vie
>       I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30359 SIG: 9
>       Application terminated.

this is my card layout XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#81C784"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="4dp"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/item_image"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="16pt"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_image"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be loading a large bitmap in the memory and it is giving out of memory exception.

To avoid java.lang.OutOfMemory exceptions, check the dimensions of a bitmap before decoding it.

You have to perform below steps to handle it -

- Estimated memory usage of loading the full image in memory.
- Amount of memory you are willing to commit to loading this image
  given any other memory requirements of your application.
- Dimensions of the target ImageView or UI component that the image is
  to be loaded into.
- Screen size and density of the current device.

Find how to do above steps from here - https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html
Or you use an image loading library that does all this for you.
There are many libraries available :[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/), [Fresco](http://frescolib.org/),  [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: i can't define getResources() inside onBindViewHolder:

Comment: the function is:  public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        viewHolder.itemTitle.setText(titles[i]);
        viewHolder.itemImage.setImageResource(images[i]);

       viewHolder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(
                decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.id.item_image, 200, 200));
    }